# Не сохраняются строки в txt файле python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я написал программу, должна сохранения текста, который ввел пользователь

```
    import os

print("Назовите имя файла и его расширение")
name = input()
stroka = 1
while True:
    a = input(f"Строка {stroka}: ")
    if a == 'выйти':
        print("Вы уверены, что хотите выйти?")
        if input() == 'да':
            exit()
        else:
            test = open(name, 'a', encoding = 'utf-8')
            test.write(a + "\n")
            stroka = stroka + 1
    else:
        test = open(name, 'a', encoding = 'utf-8')
        test.write(a + "\n")
        stroka = stroka + 1
```

Но она не сохраняет последнюю введенную строку (если после последней строки два раза не оставить пустую строку)

Comment: `stroka = stroka + 1` лучше записывать в виде `stroka += 1`

Comment: Ещё: зачем импортировать модуль os, если его не используешь?

Comment: Вообще код какой-то сумбурный. Зачем-то повторяются три строчки, хотя вместо повторения можно вставить continue.

Comment: Проблема заключается в том, что при вводе команды "выйти" ваш код не сохраняет последнюю строку перед тем, как спрашивать пользователя о выходе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот этот код должен работать нормально:

```
name = input("Введите имя файла и его расширение: ")
stroka = 1
f = False
while True:
    a = input(f"Строка {stroka}: ")
    if a == 'выйти':
        if input("Вы уверены, что хотите выйти? ") == 'да':
            if f: f.close()
            exit()
        else: continue
    else:
        f = open(name, 'a', encoding = 'utf-8')
        f.write(a + "\n")
        stroka += 1
```

Проблема в вашем коде была в том, что вы не закрывали файл перед выходом из программы. Из-за этого последняя строчка не сохранялась.

Comment: Возможна попытка обращения к не инициализированной переменной `f`.

Comment: @user207200, исправил.